# Crypto CBC module doesn't show up in /proc/crypto

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I want to decrypt an old volume that's using aes-cbc-plain

So I am on arch linux kernel 4.9.130 I enabled the cbc as modular in the kernel and installed the modules and the kernel. CBC shows up in /lib/modules/4.9.130/kernel/crypto as cbc.ko.xz

I can perform modprobe cbc fine without errors and lsmod confirms cbc is loaded.

When I check /proc/crypto | grep cbc it is missing.

Is there a place where I can check for errors during the loading of the cbc module?

Comment: anything in `dmesg`?

Comment: dmesg shows nothing in relation to the matter. I cross referenced with a mint that had cbc inbuilt and checked the kernel configuration. My deduction is there is a dependency. I just enabled every option except experimentals in the cryptography sub menu. That didn't yield me aes(cbc) either so I went ahead and copied the kernel build config of the working system to this one.

I then used 'make localmodconfig' to try trim down compilation time and finally got what I wanted. cbc(aes) in the /proc/crypto.

I'll add my .config as a pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/ddQmrMCy